# Javascript Paramenters available in Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, onavailable

I'm trying to do something like:

```
function xyz(id,name){

 $(this).spin();

 }
```

`spin()` is a jquery plugin function (spinner box), but however I want to access the id and name parameter of javascript into `spin()`. How can I do it without changing the `spin()` prototype?

Comment: how do you call the function?  `$(id).spin()`?

Comment: a link to the plugin would be useful along with why you want to access something inside it

Comment: @above  using this http://jquery-spin-button.googlecode.com/files/jquery-spin.tar.gz

Comment: That makes no sense ;)  You want id and name in spin, but you cant change the code for spin and spin doesnt use id or name anywhere in its code????

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `spin` has local variables called `id` and `name` - you can't.

Scope is determined when the function is created, not when it is called.

The normal way to do this would be to pass the variables as arguments, but that would require `spin` to accept them in the first place. Since you can't change `spin` you can't do that.

The bad way to do this would be to use globals. If `spin` is competently written, it won't be using them so, again, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that you want to apply `.spin()` to the element with the `id` in that first parameter then do this:

```
function xyz(id,name){
    $("#" + id).spin();
}
```

That is, use a jQuery (CSS-style) selector to select the element by id, then apply `.spin()` to the resulting jQuery object.

Comment: oh no , not doing something like this , actually i want to do a simple stepper but that stepper increment uniquely for each id

Comment: It seems to me your spin plugin should provide options to set increment independently. You mentioned in the question that you can't change spin, but why not? (I know you didn't write it, but you said you downloaded it so you have the source - or does the licence not allow any modifications?)